# Why does this loop forever if a non-numeric is entered, but works as intended for an out-of-range numeric

Tags: c, while-loop, scanf

I'm new to c, and I don't understand why the outcome is so different whether I enter a non-numeric char or a digit. What is the fix for this? What am I doing wrong/not understanding?

```
while ((scanf(" %d", &option) != 1) /* non-numeric input */
       || (option < 0)              /* number too small */
       || (option > 4))             /* number too large */
{
    fflush(stdin); /* clear bad data from buffer */
    printf("That selection isn't valid. Please try again.\n");
    printf("Please enter your choice:  ");
}
```

Output for digit out-of-range (correct):

```
Please enter your choice: 5
That selection isn't valid. Please try again.
```

Output for non-digit (infinte loop):

```
...
Please enter your choice:  That selection isn't valid. Please try again.
Please enter your choice:  That selection isn't valid. Please try again.
Please enter your choice:  That selection isn't valid. Please try again.
Please enter your choice:  That selection isn't valid. Please try again.
Please enter your choice:  That selection isn't valid. Please try again.
...
```

Fix for reference (use fgets() instead of fflush()):

```
while ((scanf(" %d", &option) != 1) /* non-numeric input */
       || (option_text[0] < 0)      /* number too small */
       || (option_text[0] > 4))     /* number too large */
{
    fgets(option_text, sizeof(option_text), stdin); 
    printf("That selection isn't valid. Please try again.\n");
    printf("Please enter your choice:  ");
}
```

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` is not a standard thing so it may not work. Instead skip till the next whitespace or EOL with `fgetc` or `fgets`.

Comment: Yes ```fgets(option, sizeof(option), stdin)``` worked and fixed it. The suggested question explained it, thanks!